# Using Criteria to get only base types

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm looking for way in Fluent NHibernate to get a list of all object of type PARENT 
using criteria.
I have a father object and a derived child.
The father contains a list of childs.

The problem is that when I use:

```
ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Parent))
IList<Parent> myRes = crit.List<Parnet>()
```

NH return back the list of both parent elements and the derived children elements, which is "right" b/c that is what I've asked, but that is  not what I need.
(the children elements should be only inside the father object, but since they are of type parent as well - since they derived from it... NH brings them as well using this method.)

How can I get the list of all my "father" elements without the derived children ?

This is from the first answer (@Stefan Steinegger's)

```
session
  .CreateQuery("from Parent where Parent.class == :class")
  .AddType(typeof(Parent));
```

It looks like I need something like that - but it doesn't work in Fluent NHibernate.

Thanks, 
Dani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question actually is: how do you determine if a `Parent` is a root parent? there are various approaches:

- You keep your model and define: a root is a Parent that is not inherited and is not included in any other Parent.

The part *"is not inherited"* might be easy to determine, but is actually a poor definition. When using inheritance, you should actually not care if an object you get as a certain type is actually inherited or not, this is the nature of inheritance.

The part *"is not included in any other Parent"* is hard to find out in an efficient way.

- You set a reference to an objects parent. A root is a `Parent` where its parent references null.
- You derive your Root from a common Base class. A Child is not a Root anymore, and a Root is a `Root`.

I suggest to take the last option.

---

BTW: you can filter for the exact type, but only using HQL.

```
session
  .CreateQuery("from Parent where Parent.class == :class")
  .AddType(typeof(Parent));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Actually - the parent object has no property of "ParentSeqID" as it's only the child's property. (or a property of parent which maps to ParentSeqId)
How do I add this to the criteria ? is there a "has no property" option ?

Comment: I think you can't. You can only filter for a type using HQL, I added another section to my answer.

Comment: The Session.CreateQuery("").AddType will not compile (there is no AddType There)

Comment: Sorry, I think it is called AddClass. Since it is ported from Java, there are sometimes such terms.